# Interpreting the results of an interaction plot

Tags: r, anova, data-visualization, interaction

I have data on 3 species of fish that we fed 2 different types of food and we measure the eggs they lay (number of eggs are a coefficient, but that's not important for this question). The fish species are fictious (we don't have blobfishes).

The data looks like that:

```
eggs species food
2.7  Goldfish  A
2.4  Goldfish  A
3.1  Goldfish  B
4.9  Blobfish  A
...
```

I did a 2-way ANOVA test and saw that there was a significant relation between the species and the food based on the p-value returned for the interaction between the 2 variables.

Now I drew 2 plot using R's interaction.plot:

```
interaction.plot(data$species, data$food, data$eggs)
interaction.plot(data$food, data$species, data$eggs)
```

It gives these 2 plots and I'm not sure how to interpret them:
[image]

I saw online that crossing lines meant that there was an interaction where as parallel lines mean there aren't interactions, but in the 2nd graph, the Swordfish is a parallel line. I'm not sure what to interpret exactly.

What can I visually extract from these graphs to support my previous finding that there's a significant relation (or interaction) between species and food?

Comment: Switching from food B to food A leads to an increase in the mean number of eggs for blobfish, but not the other two species - goldfish and swordfish experience a decrease in the mean number of eggs.

Comment: That we can see in the 2nd graph, right? What is the relevance of the first one then? What does it indicate?

Comment: Both graphs tell you the same thing (all you've done is switched the ordering in the graph). It's just that the second one is easier to read. With the first graph, it's slightly easier to tell which food leads to a greater number of eggs within a given species. Other than that, you get the same amount of information.

Comment: "in the 2nd graph, the Swordfish is a parallel line" isn't true. That line is reasonably parallel to the x-axis, meaning that Swordfish `egg` numbers aren't closely associated with `food`. That line, however, is _not_ parallel to the other two lines for `species`--that's the lack of parallelism that you need to examine in terms of interactions.